# deSerialise a Binary Search Tree of integers from a text file using C++

Tags: c++, serialization, binary-search-tree

I am trying to de-serialise a Binary Search Tree of integers from a text file. The text file was created using a pre-order walk. The format of the text file is:

```
10
2
#
#
19
#
#
```

where each integer is delimited by a new line and # is used to show a null child. I need to store the bst of integers in a text file and not store it in an array etc.
I am always getting an empty tree when I try to deserialize the tree. My preorder, serialise and add methods appear to work and the save file is created correctly. I debugged it and it seems the root of the new tree is always null.

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    BinaryTree bst, bst2;

    bst.add(10);
    bst.add(2);
    bst.add(19);

    cout << "BSTree 1 is : ";
    bst.preOrder();
    cout << endl;
    
    ofstream OutFile("TreeFile.txt");

    bst.serialise(OutFile);
    OutFile.close();

    ifstream InFile("TreeFile.txt");
    
    bst2.deSerialise(InFile);

    
    cout << "Rebuilt Tree is : ";
    bst2.preOrder();

        
    InFile.close();  
    return 0;
}
```

bst.h

```
class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree();

    void add(int data);
    void preOrder();
    int serialise(ofstream& OutFile); //save the BST to a text file, returns - 1 if it fails.
    TreeNode* deSerialise(ifstream& InFile); //read the BST from a text file

private:

    void add(TreeNode* toAdd, TreeNode* attachHere);
    void preOrder(TreeNode* root);
    int serialise(ofstream& fp, TreeNode* root);

    TreeNode* root;
};
```

bst.cpp

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(int theData)
    :data(theData), rightPtr(nullptr), leftPtr(nullptr)
{}

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
    : root(nullptr)
{}


TreeNode* BinaryTree::deSerialise(ifstream& fp)
{
    // Read next item from file. If theere are no more items or next
    // item is marker, then return
    string val;
    int intval = 0;

    if (!fp.eof())
    {
        fp >> val;
        if (val == "#") {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            intval = stoi(val);
            TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode(intval);
            add(newNode, root);
            newNode->leftPtr = deSerialise(fp);
            newNode->rightPtr = deSerialise(fp);

            return newNode;
        }
    }
}

void BinaryTree::add(int data)
{
    // create the node to attach
    TreeNode* toAttach = new TreeNode(data);

    //if tree is empty, must put new node here
    if (!root)
    {
        root = toAttach;
        return;
    }
    //else, make the recursive call
    add(toAttach, root);


}

void BinaryTree::add(TreeNode* toAdd, TreeNode* attachHere)
{

    if (attachHere == nullptr) {
        root = toAdd;
        return;
    }
    //we will attach to either right or left sub-tree of this node

    //if value is < root value, go left 
    if (toAdd->data < attachHere->data)
        if (attachHere->leftPtr == nullptr)
            attachHere->leftPtr = toAdd;
        else
            add(toAdd, attachHere->leftPtr); //recursive call
    else //go right
        if (attachHere->rightPtr == nullptr)
            attachHere->rightPtr = toAdd;
        else
            add(toAdd, attachHere->rightPtr); //recursive call
}


int BinaryTree::serialise(ofstream& OutFile) {

    serialise(OutFile, root);
    return 0;
}

// This function stores a tree in a file pointed by fp
int BinaryTree::serialise(ofstream& fp, TreeNode* root)
{
    // If current node is NULL, store marker #
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        fp << '#' << endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    // Else, store current node and recur for its children
    fp << root->data << endl;
    serialise(fp, root->leftPtr);
    serialise(fp, root->rightPtr);
    return 0;
}

void BinaryTree::preOrder()
{
    if (root == nullptr) {
        cout << "Empty Tree";
        return;
    }
    else {
        preOrder(root);
    }
}
void BinaryTree::preOrder(TreeNode* node)
{

    if (node == nullptr)
        return;

    /* first print data of node */
    cout << node->data << " ";

    /* then recur on left sutree */
    preOrder(node->leftPtr);

    /* now recur on right subtree */
    preOrder(node->rightPtr);
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken. The `root` parameter to `deSerialize` is definitely not null, and gets updated appropriately. However nothing ever happens to the `root` parameter, so it disappears into a black hole when the function returns. You're not saving it anywhere, and it has nothing to do, whatsoever, with a member of this class that has the same name. And that's why that class member, also named `root`, remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought my add method would deal with it. What is the best fix? Would you recommend changing the add method or the de serialise method ?

Comment: The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming states: "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do". No class method will ever deal with anything on anything else's behalf, unless it is specifically coded to do so. The add method is not designed correctly. There is no logical reason to pass the `root` parameter to it. After all, `root` is already a class member. This is what class members are: something that every method in the class can access, without having to pass it as an explicit parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the code (as shown above), and it seems to be working now.